# php check table value if empty add else check other

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

hello i have some question.
how to make if staitment if is true, loop if staitment ,else return my staff

```
function checkSlot($member_id){
$i = 1;
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  if($row['slot'.$i.''] > 0){
   $i++;
  }else{
   return true;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Why is your function itterating `$i`? Also, you need: `if(isset($row['slot'.$i]) && $row['slot'.$i] > 0){...` otherwise it will throw an error if every slot column has a value

Comment: table have 10 slots slot1, slot2 ,slot3 e tc , i need check if slot value more than 0 check next slot.

Comment: as @Robbie says, expand it.. It's unclear as to what you actually want to do!

Comment: @fees I understand that you're looping through columns with names `slot1`,`slot2`... but why are you doing this? Regardless, you need a loop (you can use a `for`,`while` or `foreach` loop, but you're probably best off with a `for` loop if you know the number of columns

Comment: @Phorce - sorry I deleted the comment as it was posted the same time as `fees` expanded enough to make it clear. But I'll note it here so people don't think you're talking to a ghost :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a looop to check all the values.

```
function checkSlot($member_id){ 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE `member_id` = '".(int)$member_id."'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
    if ($row) {
        for($slotNumber = 1; $slotNumber<=10; $slotNumber++) {
            if($row['slot'.$slotNumber] == 0){ 
                return $slotNumber;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, consider using `PDO` or `mysqli_()` functions (not `mysql_()`) as the mysql will be deprectiated. Get used to the new methods before you get used to the old and need to rewrite everything.

I've forced the $member_id to an integer to make it safe - otherwise use `mysql_real_escape_string()` as a bare minimum (or preferably `PDO` or `mysqli_()` functions as above)